# What is sender_id param in send_deferred function?

Tags: api, deferred-transactions

I tried to implement repeated execution of particular action and set this param as _self of calling contract, but the transaction gets executed only once in this case.
Then i tried to set it as time() and it worked, so has it to be unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sender_id` is just a value set by the contract that sends the deferred transaction so that later operations can refer to the same transaction.  The semantics are:

- sending a new transaction with the same `sender_id` as one in-flight will *replace* the in-flight transaction
- canceling a transaction can be achieved by passing that `sender_id` into `cancel_deferred`

So, if you want to have N transactions in-flight at the same time they need N unique ID's